# What is the TextView ID in a simple_list_item_1 layout in Android?

Tags: android

I have a custom ListView adapter that uses multiple layout types. One is the built-in type here:

```
v = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
```

How do I access the TextView on that layout? What is the ID?

```
TextView txt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(***WHAT IS THE ID***);
txt1.setText("foo");
```

And if you know the ID, how did you find it?

Comment: Look it up with code completion from android.R.id.* (shows you a lot more useful ones as well)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is `@android:id/text1`

So you need to modify your code like this

```
TextView txt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

Found here https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml

Source code is your best friend!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the ID by looking in the layout file in the SDK.

In this case the file is in `<SDK DIR>/platforms/<PLATFORM VERSION>/data/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml`, which will show that the required ID is `android.R.id.text1`.